# Jsweet library does not work in web application

Tags: transpiler, jsweet

I have tried transpiling java file to javascript file using jsweet library. It works when I executed via the main method of the java class. But the same code does not work when called via a web application hosted on tomcat. Is there any configuration needed for that ?

I am using JDK : 1.8

what I have noticed is when executed from web application :
setupCompiler() method from jsweet class 'org.jsweet.transpiler.JSweetTranspiler' returns null giving warning message : errors during parse tree